# How to have HTML value change with JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm using JS handlebars library to design a simple HTML template, which looks like:

I have a JS file as follows:

```js
import template from './entry.hbs'

let propertyVar = 0;
let html = template({
  property: propertyVar;
});

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

A handlebars template (.hbs) file as follows:

```html
<div>{{property}}</div>
```

And my index.html looks like:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Which is all good, but how can I have the variable `property` update in HTML if I update its value in the JS code.
I want to have a loop in javascript that increments property, and I want this increment to show in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the rendered data, you will have to reassign the HTML with the latest data applied to the template.

```js
/**
 * @param {Element|String} elOrSel - An element or selector
 */
const loadTemplate = (elOrSel) =>
  (el => Handlebars.compile(el.innerHTML))
  (typeof elOrSel === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elOrSel) : elOrSel);

/**
 * @param {Function} template - Handlebars template function
 * @param {Object}   data     - Template data
 * @param {Element}  target   - Target element to render HTML to
 */
const render = (template, data, target) => (target.innerHTML = template(data));

const template = loadTemplate('#entry-template');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

let propertyVar = 0;
const redraw = () => render(template, { property: propertyVar }, result);

redraw();
setInterval(() => {
  propertyVar++;
  redraw();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>{{property}}</div>
</script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to html this code `<h1 id="property"></h1>`

in your loop that have increment property add this code
`document.getElementById("property").textContent = propertyVariableName`